# Unhiding a view is very slow in CTCallCenter callEventHandler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch, core-telephony

Reposting with more concise and focused question after original question went unanswered.  Also adding more insight into the problem after another day of research:

In my app delegate (`didFinishLaunching`), I set up a `callEventHandler` on `CTCallCenter`.
The idea is that when a callState changes, I post a notification with a userInfo dict
containing the `call.callState`.  In my view, I observe this notification, and when the
`userInfo` dict contains a value of `CTCallDisconnected`, I want to unhide a view.

The problem I'm having is that the unhiding aspect is taking, almost consistenly, ~ 7 seconds.
Everything else is working fine, and I know this because I `NSLog` before and after the unhiding,
and those logs appear immediately, but the darned view still lags for 7 seconds.

Here's my code:

appDidFinishLaunching:

```
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call) {
        // anounce that we've had a state change in our call center
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:call.callState forKey:@"callState"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:self userInfo:dict];
    };
```

I then listen for this notification when a user taps a button that dials a phone number:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ctCallStateDidChange:) name:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:nil];
```

Then, in ctCallStateDidChange:

```
- (void)ctCallStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSLog(@"121");
   NSString *callInfo = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"callState"];
   if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
      NSLog(@"before show");
      [self.view viewWithTag:kNONEMERGENCYCALLSAVEDTOLOG_TAG].hidden = NO;
      NSLog(@"after show");
   }
}
```

I've tracked the problem down to the if condition in the above code sample:

```
 if ([[userInfo valueForKey:@"userInfo"] valueForKey:@"callState"] == CTCallStateDisconnected) {
```

If I simply replace that with:

```
if (1 == 1) {
```

Then the view appears immediately!

The thing is, those `NSLog` statements are logging immediately, but the view is
lagging in it's unhiding. How could that condition cause only part of it's block
to execute immediately, and the rest to wait ~ 7 seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: Process of hiding/revealing view is very fast. The problem is with the content of your view and its superview. Have you tried to profile the case with instruments? Post code where you configure view that will hide and view that will be revealed after hiding.

Comment: Thanks.  Just updated my original post.  The image in the view is 4KB, so I don't think that's a problem.  I just tried leaving the image out, and still have the lag.  Not too familiar with instruments.  Have only really looked at memory leaks through that tool, so not too sure how I'd inspect what's going on here behind the scenes.

Comment: Use time profile, it will show you call stack at every moment and how long every function worked. It will surely help you

Comment: You should check when does notification from CTCallCenter come. Maybe it is it who is late.

Comment: It's not the notification, and I know this because I can NSLog before and after the code that shows the view, in the event handler callback.  The NSLog's appear in the console immediately.  Since the second callback is after the "appear" code, I know that has run.  Problem is it's just not appearing for several seconds.

Comment: Show your callback handler method

Comment: Just updated.  I'm not getting too far with Instruments.  Nothing is over 51ms...the part where I see my callback handler getting called, ctCallStateDidChange, only lasts for 4ms.  So that function is in fact returning quickly.  I don't know where else to look to see information about the view appearing so slowly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
- (void)ctCallStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSLog(@"121");
   NSString *callInfo = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"callState"];
   if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
      NSLog(@"before show");
      [self.view viewWithTag:kNONEMERGENCYCALLSAVEDTOLOG_TAG].hidden = NO;
      NSLog(@"after show");
   }
}
```

Note:

- The parameter is an `NSNotification`, not an `NSDictionary`
- I would not compare strings with `==`
- No need to cast the view to change the `hidden` property
- Use `NO` instead of `false`

**Update**: Got an idea: Could you try the following, please, in between the `NSLog`s?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.view viewWithTag:kNONEMERGENCYCALLSAVEDTOLOG_TAG].hidden = NO;
});
```

Reading the `CTCallCenter` doc, it seems the `callEventHandler` is dispatched on "the default priority global dispatch queue", which is not the main queue where all the UI stuff happens.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  While all your suggestions are appropriate and well received (I even updated my question to use your code sample), I'm still having the exact same problem.  7 seconds before the view appears.  The problem is not that I can't satisfy the condition (even my code you edited was satisfying the IF condition), it's that it does get satisfied, the two NSLog's log, but the view doesn't appear for 7 seconds.  Also, a little off topic, but when is it necessary to cast, and when can you just leave it off?

Comment: You need to cast to your subclass if you want to access one of your own properties or methods. `hidden` is a property of `UIView`, so no need to cast here.

Comment: Also, remember @Thomas Müller, that if I change the IF condition to: if(1 == 1), it also (obviously) is satisfied, but everything works correctly.  The first log logs, the view appears immediately, and then the second log logs.  Something about that specific condition is causing a delay in the view appearing.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. Very strange.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `callEventHandler` does not run in the main queue. Maybe, in there, do all the notification center stuff on the main queue (with `dispatch_async`, like in my update). Also, I suggest adding a [grand-central-dispatch] tag to your question.

Comment: You deserve way more than an upvote and correct answer for this.  Thank you so much Thomas.  I'll need to research dispatch_async so I know what's going on and how that solved it.  Works perfectly now!

Comment: @Thomas Müller, one question.  Why did it work fine when my IF condition was simple, like if(1==1), but when I choose to test the value of my userInfo dict, I need to ensure it runs on the main queue? Since both "hidden=NO" statements appear in my callEventHandler, it's odd that I can get it to work just fine without worrying about queue's as long as my condition is very basic.

Comment: Happy to be able to help, but, to be honest, I was mostly just tapping in the dark. About the other `if` statement: one thing which I find interesting is that in that case you never had to access the `NSNotification` (which was created in the `callEventHandler` on a different thread). But why it behaved like it did doesn't make any sense to me, based on my very limited knowledge of threads and stuff like that. In other words, I can't explain it either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no problem with your hidden code. If I were you, I would comment out all the code after the call ends, and uncomment them one by one to see what is the problem.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't seem to work. in my callback handler, i uncommented everything after i show the view, and it still has a 7 second delay.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... try to call `[yourViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]` after you change hidden property. Or avoid hidden, use alpha or addSubview: and removeFromSuperview methods instead.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions @Zapko.  I just discovered that if I remove the conditions that test for appDelegate.userInitiatedCall.callState, everything appears immediately, as desired. Not sure why checking an ivar on the app delegate is taking so long.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should keep in mind that when you write `appDelegate.userInitiatedCall.callState == something` it is not checking the iVar it is calling 2 methods `[[appDelegate userInitiatedCall] callState]`. Time of performing of this methods depends on their complexity. For example, if you just synthesized them but didn't set them _nonatomic_ it would take much longer to perform them than _nonatomic_ ones. If you have several calling for some property in a method it is reasonable to make local var, in your case `Call *initedCall = appDelegate.userInitiatedCall`.

Comment: Check declarations and, if possible, implementations of all properties that you use several times in your ifs. If there will be some complex or thread safe (atomic) ones it would make sense.

Comment: @Zapko...some great suggestions.  I've tried setNeedsDisplay, alpha, and addSubview, and I'm still getting the same response.  Also, instead of looking for appDel.foo.bar, I'm passing in a userInfo dictionary with the notification I post when the call state changes.  Still having the very consistent ~7 second delay. I've definitely tracked it down to the if statement that asks if the callState == CTCallStateDisconnected.  if I change the condition to if(1==1), everything shows/hides perfectly.  Weird!

Comment: I insist that you should try to declare local var `NSString *callState = appDelegate.userInitiatedCall.callState`.By the way, CTCallStateDisconnected is string. It will be better if you check for strings equality by `[myString isEqualToString:anotherString]` method.

Comment: Thanks Zapko.  I realized isEqualToString should be used, and am actually already using it, but it's still not helping.  Took your advice about storing the callState to a string, but that's not helping still.  In my callback, I have: NSString *callState = [[appDelegate userInitiatedCall] callState]; and then I test: if ([callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected]).  Again, this condition is satisfied, and we enter into the code block (as evidenced by the NSLog's logging immediately, as expected) but the darned view still doesn't appear for 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

djibouti33,

Where you put this sentence to listen when a user taps a button that dials a phone number?on WillResignActive function?

this sentence --> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(ctCallStateDidChange:) name:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:nil];

Thanks for your time,

Willy.

Comment: The button a user taps to make the phone call has a target/action assigned to it (handleDialTap:).  Inside handleDialTap, I do a few things, one of which is call another method called dialOut:.  Inside dialOut: is where I start listening for the ctCallStateDidChange notification.  Hope that helps.